# AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property) - Is there a way to specify a black/white-list for Property Type?

Tags: .net, custom-attributes

I have a custom attribute defined as System.AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property).
I want the compiler to throw a compile error when a developer adds the attribute to a property that is a NOT a Class. Is there any way to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

No, there's nothing like that available.

However, if you're concerned about this within your own code, I suggest you write some tests which go through all the properties in all the types in all your assemblies, and check that the attribute has been applied appropriately.

Compile-time checking is best when it's feasible, but validating with tests is better than nothing :)

Comment: I'm working on a framework that other developers will use, which is why i was looking for a solution that works during compile time. Oh well, maybe it's something MS can add.

Comment: @PaulRivera: It sounds unlikely - there are lots of things which, while useful to a *few* people, would add complexity for *everyone*. I suggest you include a Testing assembly which makes it very easy for them to test this themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Don't get your hopes up, but you might be able to force a custom compiler error using something like Microsoft's Code Contracts or FxCop:

Code Contracts:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/dd491992.aspx

FxCop:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429476(v=vs.80).aspx

You might also take a look at Spec#:
http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/specsharp/